# How to modify the display sleep and sleep together again?

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, pmset

I'm using pmset to set battery-power sleep time independently of display sleep time on my 2014 15" MacBook retina. Before I did that, these values were in lock step when you changed the "turn off display after" setting in the Energy Saver control panel. If I change the control panel setting now, it only affects display sleep.

I'm curious what setting I can use to make the control panel setting affect both display sleep and sleep again?

Comment: You could do `pmset resetdefaults` see if that helps.

Comment: Well I notice that my coworkers who have not messed with their settings have sleep set to 1 in battery mode. Is "1" an undocumented special value which actually means "use the same value as displaysleep"?

Comment: No, 1 just means sleep in 1 minute as it says in the man page *"sleep - system sleep timer (value in minutes, or 0 to disable)"*. I assume that what you mean is that you can set the value of Display Sleep higher to that of Computer Sleep? Because for me it's in lock only when I try to increase Disp sleep to more than Comp sleep. Here are my [setting](http://hastebin.com/agujayajav.pas) Can you post yours by doing `pmset -g custom`

Comment: OK I think that explains the default setting then. If sleep=1 and displaysleep>1, then the effect is to put sleep in lock-step with displaysleep. I believe that is the default setting, so that jives with the UI which only offers the ability to set displaysleep under battery power.

Comment: I actually have ability to set display sleep time from Energy Save Pref Pane, for both AC and Battery power. Glad was able to help. :)